# Rspec: execute code in let and return value

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a following code for assigning value to variable before execute test:

```
 let!(:cash_payment){
    cash_payment = PaymentMethod.find_by_id(1)
    create(:payment_method, :cash) unless cash_payment
    return cash_payment
  }
```

The problem is: after run that code block, ruby doesn't return value of `cash_payment` object back to cash_payment. So after that, in my test, reference to `cash_payment` will be nil. Please tell me how.

Comment: That is because you are assigning `cash_payment` to nil and not re-assigning maybe try `cash_payment = PaymentMethod.find_by_id(1);
    create(:payment_method, :cash) unless cash_payment;
    cash_payment || PaymentMethod.last` this will cause `cash_payment` variable in the tests to be either PaymentMethod with id 1 or the last payment method created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find `PaymentMethod` with id `1` or create a new one:

```
let!(:cash_payment) { PaymentMethod.find(1) || create(:payment_method, :cash) }
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is: after run that code block, ruby doesn't return value of cash_payment object back to cash_payment.

Not true.

> So after that, in my test, reference to cash_payment will be nil

This only happens when you don't have any payment methods in the database (`PaymentMethod.find_by_id(1)` returns nil).

If that happens, you want to create a payment method from a factory girl, but you fail to assign it to anything. This value is ignored.

```
create(:payment_method, :cash) unless cash_payment
```

Should be more like

```
cash_payment ||= create(:payment_method, :cash)
```

Then it'd work. Alternatively, use what @gabrielhilal suggests. That one is good too.